# Dataframe transpose - how to get columns name right?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have dataframe like this:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 2], 'b': [3, 4], 'ent':['A','B']})

|   |a  |b   |ent 
|---|---|----|----
|0  |1  |3   |A   
|1  |2  |4   |B
```

I want to have this dataframe in form like **this:**

```
|ent  |A  |B
-------------
|a    |1  |2
|b    |3  |4
```

I can apply `df.T` or `df.transpose` but I don't get exactly what I want (header):

```
|     |0  |1
-------------
|a    |1  |2
|b    |3  |4
|ent  |A  |B
```

I'm looking for pandastic solution (renaming columns and dropping ent row after transpose for me is inelegant).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If need first column is `index` add [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html):

```
df1 = df.set_index('ent').T
print (df1)
ent  A  B
a    1  2
b    3  4
```

And if need default index:

```
df1 = df.set_index('ent').T.rename_axis(None, 1).rename_axis('ent').reset_index()
print (df1)
  ent  A  B
0   a  1  2
1   b  3  4
```

Answer (score 1):

`pd.pivot_table(df, values=['a','b'], columns='ent')`

does exactly what you want

Edit: jezrael is totally correct. The output of the displayed pivot_table function with

`df=   a b ent
    0  1 3  A
    1  2 4  B`

is

`ent A  B
 a  1   2
 b  3   4`

but if we change df to

`df=    a   b   ent
     0  1   3   A
     1  2   4   A`

the output of `pd.pivot_table(df, values=['a','b'], columns='ent')` is

`ent    A
a     1.5
b     3.5`.

Note that it is possible to apply an own function in the pivot_table argument aggfunc. 'mean' is just the default value.

Comment: Hmm, `pivot_table` aggregate data if duplicates `ent` values, not sure if OP need it.

Comment: Thanks a lot, but I only need "clean-transpose".